# What is the difference between the <span></span> tag and using span in a .css?

Tags: css, html

I have an html file that uses the `span` keyword in two different ways.

The first being in the second definition `button.groovyButton span` here:

```
button.groovyButton {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 45px;
    background:  url('../images/leftside.png') no-repeat;
}

button.groovyButton span {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: "san-serif";
    font-weight:bold; 
    color: #FF9900;
    line-height: 45px;
    background: url('../images/mainbak.png') no-repeat right;
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
```

and the second, where the button.groovyButton style is used in the html:

```
...
<body>
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <button value="Submit" type="submit" class="groovyButton">
  <span>Please wait<img src="/images/blah.gif" width="24" height="39" /></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

I see how the `<span></span>` is used to group elements together, but what about the `button.groovyButton span`?

Comment: So you can have multiple buttons with the same style without copying the code

Comment: @craig1231, but wouldn't just class="groovyButton" do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You have a selector that includes `span`, ie, `button.groovyButton span`, and you have a physical `<span>` element on the page. Are you asking what the difference is between these two?

Comment: `button.groovyButton span` only targets spans that are inside of a button that has the class `groovyButton`.

Comment: @BeeBand You need to review the basics of CSS syntax

Comment: the span seems to be superficial to me, indeed

Comment: @Jared Farrish, yes, actually I am asking that. But I guess firstly I am asking, what does `button.groovyButton span` do (and is it different from `<span></span>`).

Comment: See this demonstration of different [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html): http://jsfiddle.net/wjX7T/

Comment: @JohntheRevelator, I think you are probably right. :) But I figured I'd just have a stab at the question anyway. Just out of interest, which part of my question gave away my obvious ignorance? That would be helpful when it comes to reviewing css syntax...

Comment: You're mixing things up a bit: `<span>` is an HTML tag, `span` is a CSS selector...

Comment: Read the CSS specs on selectors: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html They are different in that a `<span>` is a physical element in the markup, and `.groovyElement span` *selects* physical elements and *applies* styles to them.

Comment: why has someone marked this question down? 6 people have attempted to answer it. Please don't mark stuff down just coz you're annoyed with the question - constructive criticism helps me and you (and everyone we know on here). Leave a comment and tell me why you marked it down... if you're man (or woman) enough! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it's saying that all instances of  that are used inside the class button.groovyButton will get the same styling unless another class is set on the span.

Examples:

```
<body>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <button value="Submit" type="submit" class="groovyButton">
      <span>Span 1</span>
      <span>Span 2</span>
    </button>
    <span>Span 3</span>
</div>
```

So in that example Spans 1 and 2 will get the styling

```
button.groovyButton span {
      font-size: 22px;
      font-family: "san-serif";
      font-weight:bold; 
      color: #FF9900;
      line-height: 45px;
      background: url('../images/mainbak.png') no-repeat right;
      position: relative;
      left: 5px;
      display: block;
      white-space: nowrap;
      padding-right: 50px;
    }
```

but span 3 will not get that styling.

Answer (score 3):

The first instance is within a css selector, defining a group of css styles.  These styles will be applied to any span that's contained within a button with a class of "groovyButton".

Your second instance is the actual HTML of the page, where the above styles will apply.  The button tag has been given the groovyButton class, so the first batch of css will apply here.  Within the button you have a span tag, which the second batch of css will apply to.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are referring to is the CSS vs HTML and how they relate? The span in your CSS is referring to the selection:

```
button.groovyButton span {...}
```

This means that the declarations you are applying to `button.groovyButton span` affect only the `span` tag(s) inside `button.groovyButton`. Any `span` tags outside of `button.groovyButton` will not be affected by the CSS declarations.

As for the HTML, `<span>content</span>`, this is what the CSS is selecting. It is a non-block element, and typically used for selection purposes, so that you may apply additional styling. There are other reasons for using spans, but in this case, that is most common use. This way you can assign additional padding, margin, line-height, color, etc.

Comment: By the way, you can make the span function like a div by assigning the following CSS to button.groovyButton span:

display: block;

Also, what is even better is that you can assign an ID to each span, or classes. Whatever you wish. This will allow for even more refinement in styling, say if you have 2, 3, or even more spans within the button tag.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a difference, one is affected by the other.  The `<span>` element is styled using the styles defined within this CSS selector: `button.groovyButton span`

Comment: Thanks - succinct way of describing the concept.

Answer (score 0):

This is to giver the span inside the button a special style because i can see that the span that is inside the button have a special style

Answer (score 0):

`SPAN` is an HTML element that displays inline (it won't make a line break like a `DIV` does).

`button.groovyelement span` is a CSS Selector that will apply the styles to `SPAN` elements that are children of buttons of the class `groovyelement`:

`<span>Hello</span>` - Doesn't get styled

`<button><span>Hello</span><button>` - Doesn't get styled

`<button class='groovyelement'><span>Style me!</span></button>` - Gets styled

Comment: No, that's not right. `groovyelement span` in your example will instead look for an element with a `class="groovyelement"` that *has* a descendent `span`, not *is* of class `groovyelement`.

Comment: i think your making things even more confusing, you may want to correct your last line of code...

Comment: @JaredFarrish: My initial answer was wrong, yes - I was too quick to type and my thoughts jumbled up a bit. This should be right though

Comment: It's important when dealing with CSS to identify that [`whitespace`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#whitespace) is a selector itself. (And I didn't downvote you, btw.)

Comment: @josh.trow, thanks. wow you edited this really quickly - would you mind posting the original code you wrote, so that JaredFarrish's comment makes sense?

Comment: @BeeBand: I think you can see the revisions by clicking the `edited X minutes ago` link, but the idea was that I didn't read your question closely enough and I was tripping over myself - I had `groovyelement span` and `<span clas='groovyelement'>` - note the lack of `button`s. Jared is definitely correct though, it was wrong.

Comment: @BeeBand - The original stated that `.groovyelement span` would select `<span class="groovyelement">`, which isn't correct. `span.groovyelement` and just `.groovyelement` would (by class name), but the space between is a descendant selector, so it would look for an element with that class name and then look for `<span>`s within to style.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - I'm glad you remembered, I don't see the 'edited X ago' link... Did I edit it too quickly for that?

Comment: @Josh - At least on my end, there isn't a "edited" link. There's a five minute hold on edit histories being saved as revisions (give or take, I'm not sure about the actual time limit).